# jqplot doesn't bind while initializaling

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I use `jqplot` for rendering bar-chart but for some reason at

`var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], { }` `$.jqplot` is always null.

I have reference to every `JavaScript` needed as i can see it in my firebug. (sometime path may be wrong)

Has anyone experienced this problem? i think i am missing a very tiny but important bit somewhere.

Any help will be appreciated.

**CODE**  (Javascript files)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqplot/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="./jqplot/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.donutRenderer.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Scripts/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.css" />
```

then i am getting my data through ajax call and pass my code to my plotChart function to render bar-graph as

```
function plotChart( targetId, result ) {

$('#' + targetId).empty();

var s1 = eval(result.Data);
var ticks = eval(result.Labels);

var plot1 = $.jqplot(targetId, [s1], {
    seriesDefaults:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {fillToZero: true}
    },
    show: true,
    series: [ { label: result.ChartTitle }],
    legend: {
        show: true,
        placement: 'insideGrid'
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks
        }
    }
});
}
```

i get data in s1 and ticks, but as $.jqplot is undefined, nothing gets displayed

Comment: can you add some code

Comment: why do you need to use eval?

Comment: @thescientist : we have this project already working using simple JavaScript stuff. I am rewriting it using signalR, so indirectly answering your question, that's how it has been working and so didnt thought much about this. Do you have any other option to get data in array format so that jqplot understands it

Comment: use JSON as your response format, and make the the Data property an array?  Maybe you should include your response in your post so we can see the same response you're seeing.

Comment: I wouldn't include jQuery twice

Comment: Result is JSON response having ````Data```` and ````Labels```` as node (if thats correct world). Eval get ````Data```` and ````Labels```` inarray format in s1 and ticks and i get ````[147, 154, 172, 21 more...]```` as s1 and similar format as ticks.

Comment: are you using asp.net?

Comment: I am using SignalR to connect to window application to get real time data which refreshes every 10 sec

Comment: Anyone, who can help me with this?

Comment: may be a bit late with this but i have a hidden value with runat server and use the return value from signalr to set this. Basically then use setinterval to replot the chart based on the hidden value if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html), don't you need to include jQuery first?

edit: I see you updated your post to show that you are including jQuery, but you include it twice?

Comment: I did have them, this tool didn't show them initially. updated

Comment: i think there is a problem while loading the resources "$.jqplot" http://feb.imghost.us/DbX5.jpg check weather the  "Scripts/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js" is available in your project directory.

Comment: @RahulKumar: that correct rahul, is their any solution to this.

Comment: @Jay are you using reference from the jqplot? or this reside in your solution?

Comment: I can confirm all the file exist, i can see all the above (reference file in my question) in Firebug

Comment: @RahulKumar: in my solution